# New "Non-file URL" Error In MacOS project Xcode8 Swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8, macos-sierra, ckasset

I have some code that worked fine prior to upgrade to Swift 3 and xCode 8.0.

```
print("Thumb", self.theTempPath!)
video["videoThumbnail"] = CKAsset(fileURL: self.theTempPath! as URL)
```

produces this in the Console

> Thumb /Users/prw/Documents/thumbTemp.jpg
>
> 2016-09-27 10:32:06.140 PA Places Data[2386:68875] Non-file URL

The print statement is for debugging only.

It appears to me that theTempPath! is a path to a file, so I am at a loss about how to address the issue. Execution does not halt, but nothing happens after CKAsset statement.

Can anyone explain what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Should have mentioned that `self.theTempPath` is of type NSURL. xCode insists on inserting "as URL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `absoluteURL` property of `NSURL` it will return `URL` object read [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurl/1414266-absoluteurl) for more detail.

```
if let url = self.theTempPath!.absoluteURL {    
    video["videoThumbnail"] = CKAsset(fileURL: url)
}
```